# every time running PyQt application script in anaconda spyder consumes lot of disk space and it is keep increasing

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

whenever I am running the any PyQt application script in anaconda spyder it seems that it consumes  at least 2GB hard drive space, and every time I run it it keep consuming the disk, my hard disk space is drastically reducing,
can anyone suggest why is this happening and what should I do to prevent this. example code is below, but I found this behavior irrespective of script.

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    

        self.setWindowTitle("Relational Views")
        self.setLayout(qtw.QGridLayout())
    
        label_1 = qtw.QLabel("Select CSV file")
    
        button_1 = qtw.QPushButton("Select file",clicked=lambda:self.get_file_and_display_variables() )
        self.clr = 0
        self.variable_ = []
        self.min_label = []
        self.max_label = []
        self.unique_ = []
    
        self.label_2 = qtw.QLabel("Filepath")
        self.label_3 = qtw.QLabel("Variables")
        self.min_ = qtw.QLabel("Min Value")
        self.max_ = qtw.QLabel("Max Value")
        self.no_of_unique_values = qtw.QLabel("Number of Unique Value")
    
        self.layout().addWidget(label_1, 0,0)
        self.layout().addWidget(button_1, 0,1)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label_3, 3, 0)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.min_, 3, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.max_, 3, 2)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.no_of_unique_values, 3, 3)
                    
        self.show()
    
    
    def get_file_and_display_variables(self):
        self.file_path, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'select CSV file')
        print(self.file_path)
    
        df = pd.read_csv(self.file_path)
    
        variables = []
        for head in df:
            variables.append(head)

        unique_values = []
        for head in df:
            x = df.loc[:][head]
            y = x.unique()
            unique_values.append(y)
            x=[]
            y=[]

            

        self.v = []
        self.v = len(variables)
    
        for i in range(self.clr):
            self.variable_[i].deleteLater()
            self.min_label[i].deleteLater()
            self.max_label[i].deleteLater()
            self.unique_[i].deleteLater()

        self.variable_ = []
        self.min_label = []
        self.max_label = []
        self.unique_ = []
    
        for i in range(self.v):
            self.variable_.append(qtw.QLabel(str(variables[i])))
            self.layout().addWidget(self.variable_[i], 4+i, 0)
        
            self.min_label.append(qtw.QLabel(str(min(unique_values[i]))))
            self.layout().addWidget(self.min_label[i], 4+i, 1)
        
            self.max_label.append(qtw.QLabel(str(max(unique_values[i]))))
            self.layout().addWidget(self.max_label[i], 4+i, 2)
        
            self.unique_.append(qtw.QLabel(str(len(unique_values[i]))))
            self.layout().addWidget(self.unique_[i] , 4+i, 3)
    
        self.clr = self.v
        print(variables)


app = qtw.QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

but, I find that it is irrespective of code

Comment: What does your script looks like?

Comment: hi, I find that it is irrespective of code

Comment: What are the typical length of your variables list (or more specifically how many labels are you adding to your grid layout)?

Comment: it depends on the number of columns that are present in the csv file that will be uploaded using gui,,     but I have run different scripts also and it shows the same behaviour, hard disk space is consumed at least 1GB to 2GB space and it keep decreasing whenever i run any pyqt5 script in anaconda spyder, i cant find any solution or related source to solve this